# Adding wine to bash profile

Tags: macos, bash, wine

I have installed wine 1.7.50 from source. There weren’t any `.dmg` or `.app` installers available on version 1.7.50 which supports DirectX11. So, I had to install it via terminal from source via the below command. Install showed me some warning but no errors were thrown.

```
./configure 
make depend 
make 
make install
```

I typed command `which wine` as it shows me path where wine got installed(I guess).

```
/usr/local/bin/wine
```

However, when I type `wine install.exe` command or any other `--version` wine is not found. How would I add wine to `.bash_profile`?

```
Last login: Sat Sep  5 10:42:22 on console
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin:/Users/abhimanyuaryan/AndroidStudioProjects/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools
$ ls -la ~/.bash_profile
-rw-r--r--  1 abhimanyuaryan  staff  554 Aug 23 19:27 /Users/abhimanyuaryan/.bash_profile
$
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add Wine as symbolic link in /usr/local/bin on a Mac.
This directory usually already is included in the path variable and the procedure works seamlessly with the app install of Wine.

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Wine.app/Contents/Resources/bin/wine /usr/local/bin/wine
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do to run `$ wine <xyz program>`. Works perfectly on my local env:

```
alias wins="open -a /Applications/Wine\ Stable.app"

# use alias to open Irfanview, require Wine
alias irfan="wins /Users/admin/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/IrfanView/$
```

The first one sets alias to Wine launching, (you can get the path by drag-dropping the Wine shortcut from Applications (Mac OSX)

The second is set with `admin` being my user.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I type `wine install.exe` command or any other
>   `--version` wine is not found. How would I add wine to `.bash_profile`?

One small thing but you do not technically want to add the `wine` binary itself to the `.bash_profile` but rather you need to *add the path* to `/usr/local/bin/` so Bash knows to search that path for any binaries you might want to run.

And the way to do that is as follows. First, using a terminal text editor of your choice, open up the `.bash_profile` file; I like to use [`nano`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nano.1.html):

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

If `.bash_profile` does not already exist that command will create it. And if the file is empty—meaning it was never created before—then just add the following line to the file:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Or if an `export PATH` value like that already exists in your `.bash_profile`, you can just squeeze `/usr/local/bin` into that assignment by just inserting `/usr/local/bin:` into the `export PATH` assignment value. Note that `:` at the end, that is a delimiter between paths you are setting in `PATH`. So—for example—I would squeeze that into an example path like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"
```

By just adding it to the beginning of that list like this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH"
```

With that done, just save the `.bash_profile` by hitting <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and answering “Y” to the prompt “Save modified buffer (ANSWERING "No" WILL DESTROY CHANGES) ?” and then hitting <kbd>return</kbd>.

Now, just reload the `~/.bash_profile` with this command:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

And then try that [`which`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/which.1.html) command again like this:

```
which wine
```

The output should be:

```
/usr/local/bin/wine
```

That basically means with `/usr/local/bin` added to your `$PATH` the system now knows to search for binaries in `/usr/local/bin/` as well as the other paths you have setup so you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Using the idea exposed by @PristineKallio I have created a script with the Script Editor (inside Applications, Utilities) with this content:

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "open -a /Applications/Wine\\ Stable.app /Users/your_user/.wine/drive_c/Program\\ Files/Some\\ Folder\\ With\\ Spaces/Program.exe"
    do script "killall Terminal"
end tell
```

Then I´ve saved it in Application format (when you save the file you get that option) and the program runs well. Then you can create an Alias or pin it to the Dock.

Please, replace "your_user" with the name of the user in the mac.